# What does “make the last word on word” mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I found the article of New Yorker magazine dealing with U.S. Supreme Court Justice,  Antonin Scalia’s scrupulousness of the usage of words under the title’ “Salia’s word game” very interesting as an English language enthusiast. 
After introducing Scalia has quoted Samuel Johnson’s Dictionary of the English Language, Noah Webster’s American Dictionary of the English Language, Timothy Cunningham’s A New and Complete Law Dictionary, Random House College Dictionary, and others of more recent vintage in Supreme Court opinions, the author says;

> “More than any other sitting Justice, he sees himself as both an
>   authority on and an arbiter of our mother tongue. This makes him, in
>   some instances, **the last word on words**".
>   http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/newsdesk/2014/06/scalia-word-games.html?printable=true&currentPage=all#ixzz34w5n6onk

What does “make the last word on word” mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The last word](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+the+final+word) , final word; final say:

> Fig. the final point (in an argument); the final decision (in some matter). (*Typically: get ~; have ~; give some one ~.) The boss gets the last word in hiring. Why do you always have to have the final word in an argument?

[The last word on words](http://www.xconomy.com/san-francisco/2011/10/26/the-webs-last-word-on-words/) is a way to stress the concept of the ultimate decision on something. The expression can be found on the web used on various contexts.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%20last%20word%20on%20words&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,last%20word%20on%20words;,c0) though ,  shows a limited use of this expression.

Answer (score 2):

"The last word" on something means the *final authority* on that subject. So "the last word on words" is the highest authority on words.

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/last+word):

> **last word**
>
> **2.** a final or definitive work, statement, etc.: *This report is the last word on the treatment of arthritis.*

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel explains, 'the [last word](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/last%20word) on words' implies someone or something that is a definitive authority on words (i.e. word definitions).

In the context given, note that Scalia being a Supreme Court justice may in some cases get to rule on a word meaning (viz. definition 2a in M-W) if it relates to a case under consideration - and as he sees himself as an authority on the language, he is more likely to take initiative in such rulings compared to his SC peers.

Hence why the magazine comments that he may be 'the last word on words', or the person having final decision on the meaning of a word (in the context of US law).

Answer (score 0):

“More than any other sitting Justice, he sees himself as both an authority on and an arbiter of our mother tongue. This makes him, in some instances, **the last word on words**".

A reference to the fact that SCOTUS is the highest court in the land and they are the last word on decisions, and indeed, defining the words of the Constitution

Answer (score 0):

The Last Word: the final argument; the bottom line in financial matters; the very latest in fashion, technology, popularity; the final authoritative, absolute answer; the very last statement or the end of a conversation or a matter.

Comment: So you've explained what "the last word" means. What would it mean to be made "the last word on words?" Are there other examples or support that you can provide to help someone asking this question?