# What do we call a grocery store’s action to hand milk and egg to a boy who was asked to buy them by his dad?

Tags: word-choice

In connection with my previous question - [What does “make the last word on word” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178473/what-does-make-the-last-word-on-word-mean),
there was the following sentence in New Yorker’s article titled, “Salia’s word game”

> “true buyer” of the handgun in question was not Bruce Abramski, who
> went to the counter, filled out the forms representing himself as the
> purchaser, and bought the gun, but his uncle, who had given him the
> money and, as arranged, took possession of the gun just after the
> sale. This, to Scalia, is sophistry. “Abramski’s uncle was not the
> "In his dissent, Scalia heaps contempt on the majority’s view that the
>
> ‘person’ to whom the gun was ‘sold.’” The “plain language of the Act”
> makes that obvious; so does “ordinary English usage.” “If I give my
> son $10 and tell him to pick up milk and eggs at the store, **no English
> speaker would say that the store ‘sells’ the milk and eggs to me.**”
> http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/newsdesk/2014/06/scalia-word-games.html?printable=true&currentPage=all#ixzz34w8wi3l5

What have the store done to "my son" in this case, "in ordinary English usage," if the store didn’t "sell" to me as Scalia asserts no English speaker would say? The store just “gave,” “handed,” “passed,” "offered," or “entrusted” milk and eggs to the boy?

I’m asking what verb is used for the shopkeeper’s action to the buyer instead of “quote unquote" sell,”**regardless** the son is actual, in effect, nominal purchaser, or just an erand boy.

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting Scalia's statement.  The emphasis is on **me**: *no English speaker would say that the store sells the milk to* ***me***. (They would say they were sold to the boy).  It's not the verb *to sell* that's in question, it's the indirect object. (me vs my son).

Comment: Apologies Yoichi-san but, this question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a misinterpretation.

Comment: Even after the edit, the store _sells_ the milk to the boy, and there is no word for the interaction between me and the store, because, as is argued in the article, _there is no (legal) interaction between me and the store_.

Comment: @oelkelens. What I’m looking for is simple - the answer : there’s no other word than “sell’ and ‘buy / purchase’ on commercial transaction against the line, “No English speaker would say that the store ‘sells’ the milk.” Period.

Comment: Cont. I’m asking just about the right verb for a commercial transaction, if any “other than ‘sell’ and ‘buy’ English speakers use.” Whether the buyer is himself, his son, or nephew is not my concern at all.

Comment: I'm asking why "sell" is in quote, not "me" in quote. Does the objective influences on the verb.  Shouln't Solia place "me" in quote rather than 'sell,' the sole verb most answerers agree, is perfect use of verb? Do you all 'down / close voters' understand my point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bruce Abramski bought a gun for his uncle with his uncle's money. Yet the majority view was that bruce's uncle was the real buyer.

Scalia called this reasoning sophistry:

> [Of course the gun store sold the gun to Bruce.] If I give my son $10 and tell him to pick up milk and eggs at the store, no English speaker would say that the store ‘sells’ the milk and eggs to **me** [but they *would* say the store *sells* the milk and eggs **to my son**.]

**Edited to add**: the grocery store *sells* milk and eggs to the person who walks in, selects the items, pays for them and walks out. There is no other verb involved: no give, take, borrow, passed on, forked over, handed, hid, pushed on him, entrusted or any other verb. Just sell.

Answer (score 2):

There is no verb for this other than "sell".  Of course the grocery store "sold" the milk to the son, and the gun store "sold" the gun to Bruce.  Regardless of whether the money for the purchase was supplied by a third party, who would then take possession of the good in question.

I don't know what Justice Scalia is on about here, exactly, but the situation in the case of the firearm is that of a "straw-man purchase", which is a defined action that is illegal if the one who provided the funds and takes possession is not legally entitled to have possession of the gun -- specifically a convicted felon, who may not so much as handle a firearm, let alone own one.  If I am entitled to own a firearm, and give some money to my nephew to go buy one for me, it is not a straw-man purchase, because I have the right to possess the firearm in my own person.

Many laws are nothing more than codified sophistry.

Comment: “There’s no verb other than “sell” and “buy / purchase” on a commercial transaction – that is the answer what I was looking for from the beginning after seeing ‘sell’ quote in Scalia’s line, “No English speaker would say that the store ‘sells’ the milk and eggs to me.”  There’s no verb other than “sell.” It’s the last word of words.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken - Scalia **is saying** that the store sold the gun to Abramski's son.  Not his uncle, who obtained it later from the son.

Comment: Thaks for your advice. I corrected the part in question.

Comment: sorry, but your entire question is an error.

Comment: I'm asking why "sell" is IN QUOTE, not "ME" in quote. Does the objective influences on the verb? Shouldn't Solia place "me" IN QUOTE rather than 'sell'- the sole verb most answerers agree with - is perfect use of verb? THe shop owner undoubtedly SOLD milk and eggs. Do you understand my point?

Answer (score 0):

The connection between the quote and the question isn't clear to me, so I'll answer as to the quote.

In the quote, you could say that Adamski is the "nominal buyer" and the uncle is the "constructive buyer".

Comment: Please reread. Scalia is saying the opposite.

Comment: @medica I agree that Scalia would disagree with that characterization.  I changed the reference to "the quote" rather than "Scalia's example".

I'm using the term nominal buyer to be the buyer in name and the constructive buyer to be the person who was the ultimate recipient.

Scalia apparently views the nominal buyer as THE buyer.

Comment: And yet, I still have not exactly answered OP's question!!

Scalia would say the word is "sell".  Those with whom he dissents would say the boy... "intermediates"?

Comment: But Scalia's argument is that the uncle was not the constructive buyer; Bruce Abramski was. What he did with the gun is irrelevant. **He** went into the store, *he* asked for a gun, *he* filled out the forms and *he* handed over the money. He *is* the buyer.

Comment: @medica, I do agree with you that Scalia is saying that.  The answer to OP's question however depends on whether OP subscribes to Scalia's belief or the other belief - and perhaps whether guns and butter (ok, milk and eggs) should be viewed the same.

Comment: The OP is wondering about the egg and boy example, it seems to me.

Comment: I repeat:I’m asking what verb can be used for the shopkeeper’s offering action to the buyer without using the word,“sell,” regardless the son is actual, in effect, nominal purchaser, or just an erand boy, in light of the text, "No English speaker would say that the store ‘sells’ the milk and eggs to me.”

Comment: @YoichiOishi - Sell: to exchange or deliver for money or its equivalent. Scalia is saying that the store *is* selling the goods to his son. You're focusing on the wrong thing. Sell is precisely the correct verb. Focus is on the word **"me"**, not *sell*. To **whom** is the store selling, to **my son** or to **me**?

Comment: @Medica. ‘Sell is precisely the correct verb. Focus is on the word "me", not sell. It’s the exact point I’m focusing on. I’m making this point repeatedly (four times) as a comment in this page. I’m insisting on that I cannot think up the verb other than ‘sell’ in commercial transaction. Unfortunately Salia put emphasis on the word on “sell” in QUOTE, not on “me’ in the line - No English speaker would say that the store ‘sells’ the milk and eggs to me.” Don’t you see Quotation marks on ‘sell’ (instead on “me)?

Comment: Cont:I don’t think Salia who is known to be meticulous about the choice and definition of words actually said “quote unquote” before saying “sell” in his verbal comment, but the article writer may have put QUOTE wrongly on “Sell, “not on “Me , which makes the line silly as No English speaker would say that the store “sells” merchandise.

Comment: Cont. I hope someone understands my point. Quotation mark on 'sells,' which is cofusing, or 'me,' which looks reasonable to me.,

Comment: @YoichiOishi With all due respect, I think you may be over-thinking this whole thing. I agree Scalia would not render an opinion saying "quote/unquote". One would need to go back to the original opinion to know exactly what he said, but it seems fairly obvious from the quote. Quotation marks do not change the meaning of the words. Please note also that the article is saying (only slightly more politely) that Scalia takes himself too seriously when it comes to "words" - he is ostentatious. I would not advise you to try to read the mind of such a man, nor to bother correcting him.

Comment: @Medica. Primary reason for my adhering to this subject is Salia’s phrase, “No English speaker would say ....” As a non-native English speaker, I’m very much alert to the expression, “English speaker would say ...” “No English speaker would say ....,” because English speakers are teacher of English language to me. If a native English speaker says, “We say this way,” we follow him. If he says “We don’t say that way,” we follow him. I hope you native English speakers understand this sentiment of non-English speaker.

Comment: I think now it’s the time I have to leave from argument on Salia’s comment, which I haven’t heard face to face from him.

Comment: PLease leave this as it is for the record.

Comment: Do you want to move to chat? No.thanks. The discussion is over.