# What is the/a word to describe an overly-authoritative author/writer?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is/are the word(s) for a person who writes/speaks with the attitude of always being right, having the final answer(s), never having their position or interpretation questioned, having the final say on a subject? One who positions him- or herself as the ultimate and final authority on a subject, who entertains no possible alternatives to their interpretation of a subject? 
"He writes as though he is the ______ on this topic." Not the authority, but a word meaning the presumed authority - seeing this as a negative trait.

Comment: I doubt he's writing with the intent of being the wanna-be authority; that's the way you/others see him.  Maybe replace the underlined with 'self-anointed authority' which keeps the negative connotation but also sounds more accurate.

Comment: @publicwireless,  "He is a self-anointed authority on the subject" works better than "He writes as if he were a self-anointed authority on the subject".

Comment: *He is a **legend in his own mind** on this topic*

Comment: *He believes his own hype*.

Comment: *"He writes as though he is the ______ on this topic."* ... it seems to me that this sentence possesses the subjunctive mood and, if so, the verb mightn't be in the best form.

Comment: I am unable to think of a single word that connotes "unabashedly self-aggrandizing, vainglorious, and unjustifiably self-important."  I think your intent is adequately conveyed by writing your sentence: *"He writes as though he were the foremost authority on this topic."*  The subjunctive mood conveys that he isn't actually the foremost authority.

Answer (score 1):

One possible expression is that he thinks he's "the last word" or "the final word" on the subject.  There's another [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178473/what-does-make-the-last-word-on-word-mean) about that phrase (with pertinent examples).

Another term that comes to mind is "the be-all and end-all."  This is [defined](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/be-all-and-end-all) in an "often jocular" sense as "a person or thing considered to be beyond improvement."

Answer (score 0):

He writes as though he is the **ultimate reference** on this topic.

*"as though" seems sufficient to provide the negative connotation*.